# Worklow - popup windows

Tags: workflow

All,
I am just a newbie. 
Can I **pop-up** a windows to open a website after the workflow finishes?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the workflow doesn't run inside the user's browser, you can't.

You can send the user a link to a page - or depending on what you are attempting to do we can find another solution.

Comment: How's about the SPWorkflowEventReceiver with WorkflowCompleted? Could we do something there?

Comment: Does not run on the user's machine as well. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

To allow pop-ups:

Click the ellipsis icon (...) in the upper right corner of your web browser, and then click Settings.

In the Advanced settings section, click View advanced settings.

In the Block pop-ups section, click the switch to Off. Pop-ups are now allowed.
To block pop-ups once again, click the switch to On.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Force-close the pop-up window.
- End background process.
- Reboot your computer.
- Use Windows' built-in maintenance function.
- Restore your system to an earlier time.
- Use Malwarebytes or Adwcleaner.
- Install Windows Updates.
- Uninstall & reinstall programs.